# Calling a WebMethod using jQueryAjax change casing

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis, asp.net-ajax

I have the following request using ajax (simplified):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DealNumber" runat="server" Width="100px" ToolTip="Deal (aka OPG)">
</asp:TextBox>
<Ajax:AutoCompleteExtender 
  ID="AutoCompleteExtender2"
  runat="server"
  TargetControlID="DealNumber"
  ServiceMethod="GetDealNumberList"
  ServicePath="/ws/WebServices.asmx"/>
```

and on /ws/WebServices.asmx (sorry my .VB):

```
 <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True)>
 <System.Web.Services.WebMethod>
 Public Function GetDealNumberList(prefixText As String, count As Integer, contextKey As String) As System.String()
return {"Test " & PrefixText & " " & ContextKey}
end function
```

Now, doing the typical F12 network trace, ajax reports:

```
Invalid method name &#39;getdealnumberlist&#39;,  method names are case sensitive.   The method name &#39;GetWTNumberList&#39; with the same name but different casing was found.
```

Who and why the casing is changed? If I modify my .asmx works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this annoying issue, I found the answer and it was very trivial.

In Visual Studio, when using `Option Compare Binary` `Option Compare Text` I was under the impression that will only affect code generation. I was wrong. Not sure what is the method to create the intermediate code for Web Services and/or AJAX, but, adding `Option Compare Text` fix the camel issue.

I personally think this is a (survivable) bug.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly causing the problem, but I experienced this issue long time ago while still using webforms page and AJAX callback to return something from web service (ASMX). I fixed this issue by putting [`MessageName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.messagename?view=netframework-4.7.2) property with method name in lowercase inside `WebMethodAttribute` like this example:

```vb
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True)>
<WebMethod(MessageName:="getdealnumberlist")>
Public Function GetDealNumberList(prefixText As String, count As Integer, contextKey As String) As String()
    Return {"Test " & PrefixText & " " & ContextKey}
End Function
```

This problem also sometimes occurred when the web service methods are tested directly, e.g. by entering URL like `http://localhost:XXXX/path/to/webservicename.asmx/GetDealNumberList`.

Comment: Alias is a good temporary fix, in my case I can rename the webservice, but why the call is changed from Camel to Lower.